# Is there a general method for solving a linear homogeneous ordinary differential equation?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am wondering if there is a general method for finding the solutions of a linear ODE of the form :

$Ly=0$

Note : the coefficients of the homogenous LODE can be variable

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is, "no". Maybe some of the questions listed under Related have already tackled this question. Worth a look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean equations of the form:
$$
y^{(n)}(t) - a_{n-1}(t)y^{(n-1)}(t)-\cdots-a_0(t)y(t) = 0
$$
with variable coefficients $a_{0}(t),\dots,a_{n-1}(t)$, then one approach could be the following. You can write the ODE in matrix form as
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{y}}{dt} = A(t)\mathbf{y}
$$
with $\mathbf{y} = [y,y^{(1)},\dots,y^{(n-1)}]$ and
$$
A(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 &\cdots &0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0&\cdots&0 & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
a_0(t) &\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & a_{n-1}(t)\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus, the solution to the ODE is given by $$\mathbf{y}(t) = \Phi(t,t_0)\mathbf{y}(t_0)$$
for some initial condition $\mathbf{y}(t_0)$, where $\Phi(t,t_0)$ is called the state transition matrix, and can be computed (or approximated if you want) from $A(t)$ only (under suitable conditions on the coeficients) using the Peano-Baker series [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix#Peano%E2%80%93Baker_series). If $A(t) = A$ is constant, the state-transition matrix reduces to the well know exponential matrix $\Phi(t,t_0) = \exp(A(t-t_0))$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I was expecting a general way to solve a homogeneous LODE, if there exists any. But I have another question, can a homogeneous LODE be solved using any sort of method or is it impossible similar to finding a formula for the fifth root of a polynomial ? In simpler terms, is it even possible to solve a homogeneous LODE in the first place ?

Comment: Do you mean finding a closed form solution without involving any special functions? It is very hard for arbitrary ODEs to have solutions in terms of elementary functions actualy. Anyway, how is the solution I gave not general enough? Is $$
y^{(n)}(t) - a_{n-1}(t)y^{(n-1)}(t)-\cdots-a_0(t)y(t) = 0
$$ not the type of ODE you were looking to solve? Please let me know if I can help more.

Comment: Q: "In simpler terms, is it even possible to solve a homogeneous LODE in the first place"
A: it depends on what you mean by "solve". If you mean manipulating the original ODE through algebraic operations and differentiation/integration  to obtain a solution, I don't think the answer is very satisfying. In general, the "tricks" you learn in a basic ODE course work for very few classes of ODEs. On the other hand, you can ensure existence/uniqueness and many other properties (e.g. stability) of solutions regardless of if you can find closed form expressions for the solution.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. Reformulating my question, I meant : Is there a general process/method that we can use to solve a homogeneous LODE, where the solution doesn't need to be in a closed form ?

Comment: I'm still confused about what you are asking then. The method I gave using the transition matrix, **is** a general process/method to solve **arbitrary** homogeneous LODE even with varying coefficients. Perhaps you are interested in the proof of why $\Phi(t,t_0)\mathbf{y}(t_0)$ though the Peano-Baker series is a solution and how this expression is derived in the first place?

Comment: Oh it's general? Sorry about that, I was under the impression it wasn't. Well, if it is indeed a general method, you have answered my initial question. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. It is general, but the peano-baker formula may result in something that cannot be expressed using elementary functions. Please let me know if you dont understand why is it general, or if you want me to clarify something else. Good luck!

Comment: But I would be very interested in the proof of why $phi(t, t_0) y(t_0) $ is a solution and how it is derived If you don't mind giving me sources.

Comment: The classic proof requires some tools a little more advanced than what is covered in a standard ODE course, but is actually simple. The idea is to "naively" integrate both sides of the vector  ODE and then use the concept of Picard iteration: https://observablehq.com/@neobourbaki/peano-baker-series